# How can I make my background have a frosted glass effect AND have curved corners? WPF .NET XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, .net-4.8

SO, I have planned my UI for an application and when it came to coding it out, I couldn't even get CLOSE to making progress as I'm stuck on the background. I've attached how I've planned my home page as well as just the plain background, but apparently it is a real struggle to have the best of both worlds and have a blurred background (where the background is slightly transparent and blurred, kind of like a fogged glass effect) as well as curved corners.

Please note that the pattern behind the background is purely to demonstrate the blurred background effect.

[The fully planned home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcU7j.png)

So obviously I tried ChatGPT but it really isn't the best at XAML so I found this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRo7mqFZ2EY

and yes it does achieve the transparency and blur effect that I'm looking for BUT due to the library used even if the corner radius is set yes you can see that it is curved however the blur effect is set to the entire window thus it still holds that rectangular shape with just the blur.

I've included my code below but does anyone have any ideas or solutions? Or any libraries that they recommend I check out?

Lastly, just for context on my coding knowledge, I'm halfway through my second year in an IT degree and I have never coded a single line of code before this, we've been covering C# since march and WPF with XAML since May (i know this problem can be pretty up there BUT I'm *normally* really good at front end and we move pretty quickly in my syllabus).

Thank you to anyone that has spent the time reading this!

```
`<Window
    x:Class="*DELETED FOR PRIVACY REASONS*"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:beh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
    xmlns:hm="http://schemas.hpod9.com/haley/mvvm"
    xmlns:hw="http://schemas.hpod9.com/haley/wpf"
    Title="Your Application"
    Width="950"
    Height="650"
    hm:WindowBlurAP.IsEnabled="True"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="#3A302F2F"
    WindowStyle="None">

    <Border CornerRadius="10">

        <beh:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <hw:BorderClipper EnableClip="True" />
        </beh:Interaction.Behaviors>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="783" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid
                x:Name="appSideBar"
                Background="Transparent"
                IsHitTestVisible="True"
                PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="appSideBar_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <Rectangle
                    Width="167"
                    Height="650"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Fill="#FF141414"
                    Opacity="0.15"
                    RadiusX="10"
                    RadiusY="10">
                    <Rectangle.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect
                            BlurRadius="10"
                            Opacity="0.25"
                            ShadowDepth="10"
                            Color="Black" />
                    </Rectangle.Effect>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
`
```

Comment: Search acrylic or mica for background effect and you will find some libraries and tons of discussions to date. For rounded corners, in the case of Windows 11, see [Apply rounded corners in desktop apps for Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners).